# Is there a captcha plugin for Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin, xmpp

When I go to a jabber conference I need to follow the links in the browser and enter a Captcha, but it's not convenient.

I know a couple of other programs where you can do the captcha within the program - PSI+, Gajim and Vacuum-Im.

Is there a similar plugin for Pidgin?

Comment: Can you go into more detail? Never heard about. Which protocol? How is it working?

Comment: You have not heard about the conference on the XMPP servers? Some conferences are protected and in order to go there you need to enter the captcha code. In the client window (for example Pidgin) comes a link to the captcha form. I need to click on the link and it will open in the browser. There will be an image code that must be entered.

Comment: Never heard about captcha on XMPP chat rooms. Sounds a little wrong to me. However, I think it's offtopic here and should be more asked at pidgin support.

Comment: Maybe, but this tag exists.

Comment: It is not about this tag but is independent from ubuntu

Comment: @frlan but it is a program that runs on Ubuntu? So it's on topic. Sure, it might be better suited to another site, but it's on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that [this has been reported as a bug](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/13193), and is closed as `wontfix`:

> We have decided to discontinue support of the QQ protocol in libpurple and Pidgin as of version 2.8.0. Other implementations are available; please investigate their use if you want to continue using QQ.